# Django: Is it a security risk to send request to templates?

Tags: django, security, django-sessions

Sometimes I wish to use multiple variables from request, and other times I use none. What, if any, security risks may arise from having the request variable available to every template?

Comment: what value you show in your template using request?

Answer (score 2):

It would only be a risk if you let untrusted people create the templates.  Generally templates  don't change.  If you don't trust someone that is creating templates, you have bigger problems (it would be easier for them to do something sneaky in the python code).

If the template was dynamically generated and you accidentally gave users a way to add information to that template, it would be a security risk. However, I don't think that is what you are proposing.